# "Required parameter: pageToken" error when attempting to register Google Drive webhooks

Tags: post, google-api, google-drive-api, webhooks, http-status-code-400

Following the guide [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/push#making-watch-requests), I'm trying to set up Google Drive "push notifications" (webhooks) so I can watch for all file changes. I need to send a one-off POST request to `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/changes/watch` to initially "register" the webhook. But I cannot seem to do this successfully; using `curl` I receive a `400 Bad Request` response.

Here's my HTTP request via `curl`:

```
curl 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/changes/watch' \
-X POST \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer access_token' \
--data-binary '{"id": "webhook", "type": "web_hook", "address": "https://example.com/webhooks", "token": "example"}' \
-vvvv
```

The response:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Required parameter: pageToken",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "pageToken"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Required parameter: pageToken"
 }
}
```

What is the `pageToken` and where do I get it? Also, how do I include it in the request (e.g. as a header)? There's nothing mentioned in the guide about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Directly from the documentation

> [Changes: watch](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/changes/watch) Subscribes to changes for a user.
>   Required query parameters
>   pageToken  string  
> The token for continuing a previous list request on the next page. This should be set to the value of 'nextPageToken' from the previous response or to the response from the [getStartPageToken](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/changes/getStartPageToken) method.

If this is the first request then you will need to use the getStartPageToken method to get the first token then there after the page token will be part of the response.

Comment: Thanks! Weird how this isn't mentioned in the guide. And why do I need a `pageToken` in order to create a webhook? I thought that was only needed for [list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/changes/list) endpoints that return paginated data...? Very strange and unintuitive.

Comment: I would also like to know why is pageToken needed?

Comment: did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

we need to send pageToken as a query parameter it is required as per docs

1. you can get pageToken by calling this [api](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/changes/getStartPageToken)
2. google drive webhook response header contains the resource-uri which can be further used for calling the changes [see here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/changes/list)

Basically they are using these pagetoken to track the changes, whenever some change occur these pagetoken values also updates.